# Mounted Combat: How to manually choose side to attack

Tags: the-witcher-3

Is there any way how to override the side where I'm going to swing with the weapon? Sometimes, especially when charging a group of enemies, I want to choose the target myself.

Sub-questions for bonus points :-)

- difference between fast and strong attack when mounted? (I didn't find any)
- using horse's kinetic energy to inflict damage possible? (doesn't seem so)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot choose manually, it will always be based on target selected. However, you can lock onto the enemy and swap between who is selected and ride to whichever side you prefer. Not sure of your system, but on PS4 you can click in the right(?) stick and flick left and right to swap.

As far as your other 2 questions, I believe there is no difference in attack type (from what I can tell, although I don't have proof at the moment). And you will do different damage on horseback, but the speed of the horse doesn't come into play (from personal experience). I've simply walked Roach in and it does the same damage and a full gallop. Roach also doesn't appear to damage enemies by physically colliding with them.

Comment: I'm only "pretty sure" about the PS4 control I mentioned. I haven't played recently so my memory *might* be a tad fuzzy...

Comment: I have PC, but play with a Logitech controller with x360ce and yeah, it's right-stick-press to lock onto enemy and flick it to swap. Actually, what I meant with the horse speed is whether the horse itself does damage when it hits an enemy, but I don't think that's the case (would make mounted combat too easy).

Comment: Ah! I will edit my answer to reflect that as well. But no, I don't notice any collision events between Roach and enemies... Roach's collisions with enemies/objects aren't the greatest part of this game in my opinion... Hope my answer helped anyway!

Comment: In my experience, a correctly executed charge attack will always one-shot a human enemy, even one of a significantly higher level than Geralt.

Comment: I have to strongly disagree here. Playing on Death March, I've definitely had "trouble" with human enemies despite being on horseback.